# Add count grand total from separate tables

Tags: mysql, math, count

I have 2 tables which have both references to countries.
This is via a field country in table1 and/or table2.

I can count the amount via the following statement

```
SELECT co.*,  
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 m WHERE m.country=co.id) AS mCount, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 e WHERE e.country=co.id) AS eCount FROM countries co
```

The result is something like:

```
| id | name      | mCount | eCount |
```

But I want to add the value in mCount to the value of eCount.
I was expecting a simple plus sign, like:

```
SELECT co.*, mCount+eCount AS grandTotal
```

but this is not working. How can I add these columns in the query?

Comment: `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 m WHERE m.country=co.id) +
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 e WHERE e.country=co.id) AS grandTotal`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1- You Could use your query as derived table.

```
SELECT dt.*, (dt.mCount + dt.eCount) AS grandTotal FROM 
(SELECT co.*,  
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 m WHERE m.country=co.id) AS mCount, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 e WHERE e.country=co.id) AS eCount FROM countries co
) AS dt;
```

2- You can further select the calculated column

```
SELECT co.*,  
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 m WHERE m.country=co.id) AS mCount, 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 e WHERE e.country=co.id) AS eCount,
   (SELECT mCount + eCount) AS grandTotal
 FROM countries co
```

3- You can also define user-variable (*discouraged*)

```
SELECT co.*,  
    @mCount := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 m WHERE m.country=co.id) AS mCount, 
    @eCount := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 e WHERE e.country=co.id) AS eCount,
    (@mCount + @eCount) AS grandTotal
 FROM countries co
```

I hope you will like #2 the most :)

Comment: @vincent Happy to help. :)

Comment: @Vincent updated answer with two more ways, I hope this answer now deserves an upvote from you :)

Comment: Happy to help :-)